# Issue with training single class for Unet++

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, medical-imaging

```
model.train()
for epoch in range(3):

  running_loss = 0.0
  for i,data in enumerate(train_loader,0):
    inputs,labels,_ = data
    inputs = inputs[:,None,:]
    #labels = labels[:,None,:]
    print(inputs.shape)
    inputs = inputs.to(device=device)
    labels = labels.to(device=device)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    #print("Input: ", inputs.shape)
    #print("Labels: ",labels.shape)
    outputs = model(inputs)
    #thresh_output = threshold(outputs,0.5)
    loss = criterion(outputs,labels)
    #dice_score = dice_loss(thresh_output,labels).item()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    #wandb.log({"Train_Loss":loss})
    if(i%500 == 0):
      scheduler.step()
    running_loss += loss.item()
    # if(i == 1000):
    #   break
    print("Epoch : {}, iteration : {} and Loss : {}".format(epoch+1,i+1,loss.item()))
```

The code is given above. I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
torch.Size([1, 1, 256, 256]) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:1944: UserWarning: nn.functional.sigmoid is deprecated. Use torch.sigmoid instead. warnings.warn("nn.functional.sigmoid is deprecated. Use torch.sigmoid instead.")
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 16 outputs = model(inputs) 17 #thresh_output = threshold(outputs,0.5) ---> 18 loss = criterion(outputs,labels) 19 #dice_score = dice_loss(thresh_output,labels).item() 20 loss.backward()

2 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction) 3053 else: 3054 reduction_enum = _Reduction.get_enum(reduction) -> 3055 if target.size() != input.size(): 3056 raise ValueError( 3057 "Using a target size ({}) that is different to the input size ({}) is deprecated. "

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: Could you print the shape of the output and the labels of your model? It is probably a tuple and you need to select the first object.  I guess this would work 
```
loss = criterion(outputs[0],labels)
```
but more info would be helpful.

Comment: The output is a tuple so I just wrote print(output) and this is what I have:           (tensor([[[[0.5195, 0.5195, 0.5195,  ..., 0.5407, 0.5407, 0.5407],
         
          [0.5596, 0.5596, 0.5596,  ..., 0.5975, 0.5975, 0.5975]]]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>), tensor([[[[0.5616, 0.5616, 0.5616,  ..., 0.6373, 0.6373, 0.6373] ..]]]]. .The length of the tuple is 3

Comment: I also tried your fix @Hatem. It gave me this error: 

   3056         raise ValueError(
   3057             "Using a target size ({}) that is different to the input size ({}) is deprecated. "
-> 3058             "Please ensure they have the same size.".format(target.size(), input.size())
   3059         )
   3060 

ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([1, 256, 256])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1, 256, 256])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.